# best_in_place updated data doesn't display until page is refreshed

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, best-in-place

Realize there's a question that's exactly like this, but the solution didn't help me ([best_in_place gem, view not displaying updated edit without page reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213293/best-in-place-gem-view-not-displaying-updated-edit-without-page-reload)).

FWIW, I'm also getting a 422 Unprocessable Entity error in the console:

```
Failed to load resource: <update path> the server responded with a status of 422 (Unprocessable Entity
```

But the edit IS going through. Database is being updated fine. It's just that until I refresh the page, I don't see the updates.

Here's my code:

```
def update_ri_notes
    @ri = Item.find_by_id(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
        @ri.update_attributes(update_ri_notes_params)
        @ri.save
        format.json { respond_with_bip(@ri) }
    end
end

<%= best_in_place ri, "admin_notes", as: :input, url: update_ri_notes_path(ri) %>

jQuery(".best_in_place").best_in_place();
```

Because the code is working, I won't post the routes or the `update_ri_notes_params`, we can assume those are correct.

My Gem versions:

```
ruby '2.1.2'
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'best_in_place', '~> 3.0.1'
```

Comment: I don't have experience using this gem but usually in my projects, when the issue is about the need of refreshing the page, it always about the `turbolinks`. So just try deleting the turbolinks from `application.js` and from your `application.html.erb`

Comment: i have `turbolinks` off already (yes am familiar  with this problem)